# A problem in open mapping theoram from Kreyszig Section 4.12 Problem 6

Tags: functional-analysis

I am studying Functional analysis from Kreyszig book and can somebody please help with this problem

> **Problem:** Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach Spaces and $T : X \to Y$ be an injective bounded linear operator. Show that $ T^{-1} : \mathscr R(T) \to X$ is bounded iff $\mathscr R(T)$ is closed in $Y$.

Can somebody please give hints on how to proceed through this question.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  What have you tried?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  for => I tried using bounded linear operator property of inverse of T and I assumed an x in R( T) closure such that there exists a sequence ( $x_n$) ----> x but I am not able to show x belongs to R(T)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom   <= I assumed R(T) to be closed but I don't know how to prove $ T^-1 $ to be bounded using boundedness of T

Comment: Great! Sounds like you're moving in the right direction.  When posting questions on the site in the future, please include your ideas in your post along with your question.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  Will keep in mind. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hints:**

- If $T^{-1}$ is bounded and $(y_n) \subset \mathscr R(T)$ converges to $y \in Y$, consider the sequence $(T^{-1}y_n) \subset X$.
- If $\mathscr R(T)$ is closed, then $T$ defines a bijective and bounded linear map between the Banach spaces $X$ and $\mathscr R(T)$. Consider the theorems that are proven in 4.12.

Comment: If R(T) is closed how does an injective map becomes bijective ?

Comment: and even if I assume it then how  inverse of T becomes bounded can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Assuming Inverse of T to be bounded then R(T) is closed this side is clear to me.

Comment: I mean if we change the codomain from $Y$ to $\mathscr R(T)$, then the map is now also surjective

Comment: sorry was very silly to ask for it. Yes now by bounded inverse theoram I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Adding clarity to the hints/comments that were correctly stated.

Note that $R(T) \subset Y$.

For $(\Rightarrow)$ assume that $T^{-1}$ is bounded. Then, by definition, there exists a $M > 0 $ such that : $$\left\|T^{-1}y\right\| \leq M \left\|y\right\|, \; \forall y \in R(T) \subset Y$$

Take $\{y_n\}_n^\infty \subseteq R(T)$ with $y_n \to y \in Y$. Then, there exists an $\varepsilon >0$ such that $\left\|y_n - y \right\| < \varepsilon, \; $ for all $n \geq n_0 \in \mathbb N$. But, this also means :

$$\left\|T^{-1}(y_n - y)  \right\| \leq M\left\|y_n - y\right\| < \varepsilon, \forall n \geq n_0 \in \mathbb N$$
Thus, the sequence $\left\{T^{-1}y_n\right\}_n^\infty \subset X$ is convergent as well with $T^{-1}y_n \to T^{-1}y$ which means that $y \in R(T)$, thus $R(T)$ is closed in $Y$.

For $(\Leftarrow)$, assume that $R(T)$ is closed in $Y$. Since $R(T)$ is a subspace of the Banach space $Y$, being closed implies that it is also a Banach space. This is easy to prove, as taking a Cauchy Sequence in $R(T)$  will straight-forwardly lead to the sequence converging to a point in $R(T)$, since it's closed. Considering now that since $R(T)$ is closed in $Y$, the expression of the operator $T$ can be "renamed" as $T : X \to R(T)$. Thus, we have a bounded linear bijection on our hands and by a consequence of the Open Mapping Theorem (Bounded inverse theorem - Rudin 1973, Corollary 2.12) we have that $T^{-1}$ is also continuous (bounded).

Comment: Notably, the bounded inverse theorem is also given as theorem 2 of section 4.12 in Kreyszig's book (the section from which these problems are taken), hence the second hint.

Comment: Also, my approach to $\implies$ would be to avoid the $\epsilon$-$n$ proof by simply remarking that a linear operator is bounded iff it is continuous.

Comment: By writing $T^{-1}(y_n-y)$, you're assuming $y$ is in the range of $T$, which is what you're trying to show.  No?

Comment: @Rebellos Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Pretty sure about it, just don't have a view of the book atm so I cited by the Rudin copy that I have (also a wikipedia cite I think). Sure, you can avoid it by the remark you noted.